# when I am trying to get values from checkbox in PHP- i get "on" as an output - how is that?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

when I am trying to get values from checkbox in PHP , I get 
this as output, printing $_POST

```
Array ( [days] => on [submit] => save )
```

the view code

```
        $days_numbers = explode(',',$user->work_days);
        $week = array('Saturday','Sunday' ,'Monday','Tuesday' ,'Wendnesday' ,'Thursday' ,'Friday');
         ?>
       <form method='post' action='' >
       <?php
            for($i=0 ; $i< count($week); $i++)
           {
        if(in_array($i,$days_numbers))
          { echo "<input type='checkbox' name='days' checked >" . $week[$i]. "<br/>";
         }else 
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='days'  >" . $week[$i] . "<br/>";
         }
          ?>
```

Comment: This is how checkboxes work, if it is checked - the value  is `on` otherwise it is not submitted at all.

Comment: What were you expecting the value to be set to?

Comment: you have to set value for checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` element is missing with `value` attribute

replace

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='days' >" . $week[$i] . "<br/>";
```

with

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='days' value=".$week[$i]." >" . $week[$i] . "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that i forget to get write html view like this:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='days[]' value='$i' checked >" . $week[$i] . "<br/>";
```

I forget to give value of input so the output was `on` and also get the value as an array by adding name `name="days[]` .